# React Button not registering when pressed

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have 2 Buttons. Delete and Save. Depending if the state of editMode is true or false it will display on of these. But my problem is that the Save button is not registering anything at all. I tried pretty much everything. What can be the problem here?

```
<MaicoButton color={'secondary'} textButton={true} onClick={onEdit}>
              {t('actions.edit', { defaultValue: 'Edit' })}
            </MaicoButton>
            {!editMode ? (
              <MaicoButton
                color={'primary'}
                textButton={true}
                style={{ marginLeft: 24 }}
                onClick={() => onDeleteProfile(currentUserId)}
              >
                {t('actions.delete', { defaultValue: 'Delete' })}
              </MaicoButton>
            ) : (
              <MaicoButton
                color={'primary'}
                textButton={true}
                style={{ marginLeft: 24 }}
                onClick={() => console.log('Test')}
              >
                {t('actions.save', { defaultValue: 'Speichern' })}
              </MaicoButton>
```

EDIT: I am sorry here is more code:

```
const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false)

const onEdit = () => {
    setEditMode((editMode) => !editMode)
  }
```

Comment: have you tried to add type="button"?

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I am sorry these are <SelfDefinedButtons> and I have the handleClick defined somewhere else. But I use that for all my Buttons and they all work fine, except this one.

Comment: Could you please provide more code? Especially where `editMode` is defined and what changes its value.

Comment: can you add your <SelfDefinedButtons> ?

Comment: @LogiBaer the code you added in Edit is it in the same component as the first code where you have MaicoButton buttons ? if yes the code is working https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-clarke-s2lt74?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have problem with `editMode` variable- try to render it on frontend `<h2>{editMode}</h2>` and check what is happening.

Maybe try to change `!editMode ?` with `editMode == null || editMode == false ?`

Another useful thing would be to eliminate all additional problems, that might occure- try render two buttons with no additional functions and properties attached to it.

```js
<h2>editMode current val= {editMode}</h2>

{(editMode == null || editMode == false) ? (
                  <Button
                    color={'primary'}
                    textButton={true}
                    }
                  >
                   Delete button
                  </Button>
                ) : (
                  <Button
                    color={'primary'}
                    textButton={true}
                    }
                  >
                    Save button
                  </Button>
                )}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @NightBird said maybe the problem comes from state of `editMode`, here I tried this code and it's working

```
{!editMode ? (
        <button
          color={"primary"}
          style={{ marginLeft: 24 }}
          onClick={() => onDeleteProfile(currentUserId)}
        >
          btn1
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button
          color={"primary"}
          style={{ marginLeft: 24 }}
          onClick={() => console.log("Test")} // not registering
        >
          btn2
        </button>
 )}
```

here is the link if you want to try it :
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-clarke-s2lt74?file=/src/App.js:339-744

Otherwise maybe you have to share with us how the value of `editMode` get changed